# which reference to heap allocated point is right?

Tags: rust

Before I read the book, the reference to the heap is like:

```rust
let v: Vec<f64> = vec![0.0,  0.707,  1.0,  0.707];
let a: [f64; 4] =     [0.0, -0.707, -1.0, -0.707];

let sv: &[f64] = &v;
let sa: &[f64] = &a;
```

[image]

(from Programming Rust)
sv is a reference to heap so it points to the same address in heap as v.

But I read a article from https://www.net.in.tum.de/fileadmin/bibtex/publications/theses/2018-ixy-rust.pdf .

```rust
fn main(){
    let s = String ::from("hello");
    let r = &s;
    let t = s;
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

(the code can't be run cause it use reference after move)
[image]
emmmm, r just point to the address in stack.Yeah, it is a truly reference but reference in rust is pointer (right?).
This image is the same as the above if the value is stack allocated.And it's more nature explaining why can't use borrow later after move.

So, which is corrent?

Comment: > `sa` is a reference to heap so it points to the same address in heap as v. 

Do you mean `sv` here?

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix oh, my bad, I will fix it thx~

Comment: I checked the book ch4 and the note I took for the first picture, it's all about slice, I just miss the prerequisite. What a silly question 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are both correct in their own way.

A `Vec<T>` can be borrowed either as a `&Vec<T>` or as a `&[T]`. Likewise, a `String` can be borrowed either as a `&String` or as a `&str`. Rust will automatically coerce (via [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)) the first to the second when the second is expected.

In the first code sample, `sv` is explicitly declared as a slice. `&v` initially produces a `&Vec<f64>`, but this reference is implicitly coerced to a slice so that it can be assigned to `sv`.

However, in the second code sample, the type of `r` is not specified. Rust will therefore infer its type to be `&String`, because coercions don't happen unless they are necessary.

A `&Vec<T>` and a `&String` both look like the second picture. A `&[T]` and a `&str` that refer to the interior of a `Vec<T>` or `String` both look like the first picture.

Comment: Oh I just missed the type is a slice, your answer makes good sense. Thx. :)